# Docker container stops responding to network calls

Tags: python, django, docker, gunicorn

I've my django application running using gunicorn inside docker container. Randomly, the container stops responding to network calls. Container is up and running. I've checked the stats too for cpu or memory usages and they seem to be fine.
My docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:50:17 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:50:17 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Curl command response:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8001 (#0)
> GET /api/health/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8001
> Accept: */*
>
```

No response for above is received. Although ping inside the container works fine.

My fabfile looks like this:

```
def create_gunicorn_container(tag_name, version, port, network=None):
    docker_options = env.copy()
    docker_options.update({'tag_name': tag_name, 'version': version, 'port': port})
    if network:
        docker_options['network'] = network
        env.sudo(
            'docker run -v %(log_root)s:/ebs1/logs  --name my_app_server -p%(port)s:8001 --network=%(network)s ' \
            '--env-file=%(env_file)s -itd %(DOCKER_REGISTRY)s/%(tag_name)s:%(version)s ' \
            '%(gunicorn_script_path)s' % docker_options)
```

Docker File:

```
# Dockerfile

# FROM directive instructing base image to build upon
FROM python:2-alpine

ARG req_file=requirements.txt
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements /usr/src/app/requirements
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app
COPY external_config /usr/src/app/external_config

RUN apk add --update bash \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    build-base libxslt libxml2 libxslt-dev libxml2-dev  postgresql-dev libffi-dev \
    && pip install -r $req_file \
    && find /usr/local \
        \( -type d -a -name test -o -name tests \) \
        -o \( -type f -a -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \
        -exec rm -rf '{}' + \
    && runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /usr/local \
                | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
                | sort -u \
                | xargs -r apk info --installed \
                | sort -u \
    )" \
    && apk add --virtual .rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    && mkdir -p /ebs1/logs \
    && mkdir -p /var/logs/b2b \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/scripts/

COPY myapp/ /usr/src/app/
COPY scripts /usr/src/app/scripts

VOLUME /usr/src/app/static

EXPOSE 8001
```

I don't see any docker logs when this happens. I run `docker logs b2b_app_server --follow` for this. Also, this gets fixed only after I restart docker service itself, until then no response is returned for the curl above.

If it's a known problem, solution would be great otherwise what all other parameters / tools I should look into to debug this or fix this ?

Gunicorn script:

```
from psycogreen.gevent import patch_psycopg

bind = "0.0.0.0:8001"

workers = 4

worker_class = "gevent"
timeout = 7200

loglevel = 'debug'

errorlog = "/ebs1/logs/gunicorn.error.log"
accesslog = "/ebs1/logs/gunicorn.access.log"
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'

proc_name = "myapp"


def post_fork(server, worker):
    # patch psycopg2 for gevent compatibility
    patch_psycopg()
```

Comment: What is your docker file?

Comment: Please add more details: Dockerfile, logs, related code...

Comment: Added more details. I don't get any logs when this happens. Also, to fix this need to restart my docker service itself. Until then, my curl command doesn't return any response, just waits indefinitely.

Comment: So its not docker but gunicorn. I tried to curl inside container and it doesn't return any response. Added gunicorn script above. I see several connections in CLOSE_WAIT on netstat

Comment: Having the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @vivek do you have long running requests, i.e. requests with high response times. We have other systems too with similar configurations, but they work well with timeouts like within 10 secs. but with high timeouts, like more than 30 secs or so, it starts showing same issue.